# mod_rewrite activated but error logs

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

The mod_rewrite is running on my system but I still have an error at the apache2 error_logs.

```
me@server:# ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled | grep rewrite
rewrite.load
```

Content of rewrite.load

```
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

The error log

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/mod_rewrite.so.' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/mod_rewrite.so.: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/mod_rewrite.so.' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/mod_rewrite.so.: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/mod_rewrite.so.' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/mod_rewrite.so.: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/mod_rewrite.so.' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/mod_rewrite.so.: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I copied the File mod_rewrite to the folder **/usr/lib/php5/20090626/**, checked that the file is present:

```
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 63488 Mai 4 17:41 /usr/lib/php5/20090626/mod_rewrite.so
```

and restarted apache2 but still same errors. Any idea?

Comment: Can you post the content of rewrite.load file? Also try to make a `ls -l /usr/lib/php5/20090626/mod_rewrite.so*`, just to check for permissions. Even it is possible apache is trying to load file with period at the end ...

Comment: in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load

Comment: Edited my post.

Comment: Just be aware this is a PHP Warning, not an apache error. Try to disable just for a while PHP in your servers just to check if it starts weel without PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mod_rewrite` is an Apache module, but based on the error message you posted, it looks like you must have an entry in `php.ini` that is similar to:

```
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626/mod_rewrite.so.
```

PHP cannot load mod_rewrite as an extension, and also it is saying the file referenced does not exist.

Find the line in php.ini that is trying to load extension mod_rewrite and delete it and the log messages should go away.

Comment: The line is like here **extension = mod_rewrite.so.**

Comment: That is the line you want to delete from php.ini.  mod_rewrite is an Apache module and shouldn't be loaded by PHP since it does not exist in the PHP extension directory nor is it compatible with PHP.

Comment: Ok I removed it but seems I have more than one php.ini File.. Removed from all of them and restarted apache2 but it still gives out the error. Will take a look inside all files again.